# Reference to own wsdl url

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, glassfish, jax-ws

I'm building a web service that's supposed to register on another server by sending its wsdl URL to that server.

I built a very basic web service in Netbeans,

```
@WebService
public class RegisterTest{
    @WebMethod(operationName = "emphasize")
    public String emphasize(@WebParam(name = "inputStr") String input){
        return input + "!!!";
    }
}
```

and Netbeans automatically directs me to localhost:8080/RegisterTest/RegisterTestService?Tester, and naturally, the wsdl can be found at localhost:8080/RegisterTest/RegisterTestService?wsdl.

How would I programmatically get this URL?

Edit:
I've noticed that the only place that seems to store this URL is the glassfish server itself. The context-root seems to only be found in glassfish/domain//config/domain.xml.
Is there a nice way of accessing the glassfish server APIs? I can easily get the endpoint address through the UI in applications > serviceName > View Endpoint, is there a programmatic way of doing this?
I've tried looking through asadmin commands, but can't seem to find anything there that gets the context-root or the endpoint URL either.

Comment: Have you found any way to programmatically get the url finally ?

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but should be pretty close to what you're looking for:

```
@WebService
public class RegisterTest
{
    @Resource
    private WebServiceContext context;

    @WebMethod(operationName = "emphasize")
    public String emphasize(@WebParam(name = "inputStr") String input)
    {
        return input + "!!!";
    }

    @WebMethod(operationName = "getWsdlUrl")
    public String getWsdlUrl()
    {
        final ServletContext sContext = (ServletContext)
            this.context.getMessageContext().get(MessageContext.SERVLET_CONTEXT);
        final HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)
            this.context.getMessageContext().get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST);
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append(req.isSecure() ? "https" : "http");
        sb.append("://");
        sb.append(req.getLocalName());

        if ((req.isSecure() && req.getLocalPort() != 443) || 
            (!req.isSecure() && req.getLocalPort() != 80))
        {
            sb.append(":");
            sb.append(req.getLocalPort());          
        }

        sb.append(sContext.getContextPath());
        sb.append(RegisterTest.class.getSimpleName());
        sb.append("Service?wsdl");

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```